# Repeat elements of matrix based on counts in vector

Tags: r, vector, matrix

I have two dataframes (df) that share a column header named `plot.id`.  In the 1st df, `plot.id` records are repeated a variable number of times based on the number of trees monitored within each plot. The 2nd df only has a single record for each `plot.id`, and contains a variable named `load` that is collected at the plot-level (not tree-level like in the 1st df) and thus is only listed once per plot record.

OBJECTIVE:  I need to repeat the `load` values from the 2nd df based on how many times `plot.id` is repeated in the 1st df (all plots are repeated a different number of times). My example dfs are below:

```
 df1 <- data.frame(plot.id = rep(c("plot1", "plot2", "plot3"), c(3,2,5)),
             tree.tag = c(111,112,113,222,223,333,334,335,336,337)) 

 df2 <- data.frame(plot.id = c("plot1", "plot2", "plot3"), load=c(17, 6, 24))
```

I have gotten close to solving this, but alas I'm on day 2 of problem-shooting and can't get it!

Answer (score 0):

Use `match`:

```
df2[match(df1$plot.id,df2$plot.id),]
```

The result of the above is:

```
    plot.id load
1     plot1   17
1.1   plot1   17
1.2   plot1   17
2     plot2    6
2.1   plot2    6
3     plot3   24
3.1   plot3   24
3.2   plot3   24
3.3   plot3   24
3.4   plot3   24
```